# Is it possible to create virtualDestinations and compositeQueue once the active-mq broker has been started up?

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic, messagebroker

Consider the following scenario :

There are lets say 4 micro-services , each micro-service is supposed to have its own queue . Lets use the below scenario

1. Microservice A --> queue.A
2. Microservice B --> queue.B
3. Microservice C --> queue.C
4. Microservice D --> queue.D

Now all the above microservices are supposed to send messages to a master queue , lets call that **queue.master** . When microservice A wants to send a message to microservice B , it is going to send it to the master queue , the master queue is going to route it to the microservice B and so on . In other words no microservice queue knows about the queues of each other , it only knows about the master queue and the master queue is going to "route" the messages accordingly .

Now the problem comes in the configuration of the above scenario . 
For XML based , it will be quite simple and straightforward . 
I will define a `<destinationInterceptors>` tag along with `<compositeQueue>` and `<forwardOnly>` tags like so :

```
<destinationInterceptors>
        <virtualDestinationInterceptor>
            <virtualDestinations>
                <compositeQueue name="queue.master" forwardOnly="false">
                    <forwardTo>
                        <queue physicalName="queue.A" />
                        <queue physicalName="queue.B" />
                        <queue physicalName="queue.C" />
                    </forwardTo>
                </compositeQueue>
            </virtualDestinations>
        </virtualDestinationInterceptor>
    </destinationInterceptors>
```

Also i will use selectors in the tags so that it can "filter" out the messages and send them accordingly . 
The above XML based scenario works as expected . 
But I want the above configuration to also be used during the execution of the program . 
Basically what I want to do is :

- The Broker is going to start up
- Microservice A starts up , will send a message or a web request to the broker saying " Hi i am up , create a queue for me and bind it with the master queue" .
- Microservice B starts up and does the same .

So far what i have done is created the broker via java API calls and configured the virtualdestination and composite queue via java methods and classes like so :

```
   VirtualDestinationInterceptor virtualDestinationInterceptor = new VirtualDestinationInterceptor();
    CompositeQueue compositeQueue = new CompositeQueue();
    Queue queue = new ActiveMQQueue("queue.A");      // create the child queue of microservice
    compositeQueue.setName("master.queue");         // the master queue . 
    compositeQueue.setForwardTo(Arrays.asList(queue));

    virtualDestinationInterceptor.setVirtualDestinations(new VirtualDestination[]{compositeQueue});
    DestinationInterceptor[] destinationInterceptors = new DestinationInterceptor[]{virtualDestinationInterceptor};
    brokerService.setDestinationInterceptors(destinationInterceptors);
```

The above piece of code resides a `BrokerService` bean that is inside a @Configuration class . 
When the springboot app ( broker ) starts up , it creates the above child.queue and binds it with the master.queue ( all is fine and perfect ) BUT i want to do the above even after the broker has been setup .

For this I created a small service class and a controller class and put the above piece of code in a method called `createQueue(String queueName)` and used that in my controller . 
When that endpoint is accessed , nothing happens . No errors no warnings , the code gets executed **but its not reflected in the broker** . I am not able to see the newly created queue and sending the message to the master queue is not forwarding it to child queue .

Is this scenario even possible ? Configuring and making compositeQueues during runtime ?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out their documentation online is not consistent.
In this question (https://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-difference-between-a-virtual-topic-and-a-composite-destination)  it explicitly states the following statement :

> The main difference between a Virtual Topic and a Composite
>   Desetination is that with a **Composite Destination the list of consumer
>   destinations is static and hard wired**. Whereas with a Virtual Topic at
>   run time a new consumer or queue can be created dynamically and addded
>   to the subscription without having to reconfigure the broker.

However ! In this page where the release notes of version 5.9 are present ( https://activemq.apache.org/runtime-configuration ) it states the certain tags are runtime configurable . 
The documentation should be consistent throughout .

p.s just incase anyone wants to do it : 
You have to add the `<runtimeConfigurationPlugin checkPeriod="1000" />` inside the broker configuration and also use this attribute `start="false"` inside the main broker tag.

Reference for above : https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_a-mq/6.1/html/managing_and_monitoring_a_broker/fmqadminconfigsoloruntime